# Facebook GraphAPI get short lived access token without going to Generator

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm really confused what people do to get an access token for their Facebook account without going into the Facebook GraphAPI Generator? I have an account with 20 pages, when I create an 'app token', I get an error when I want to access the 'feed' endpoint in the GraphAPI so I'm guessing I have to use the short lived access token.

I have gone here to create a short lived access token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%26&version=v10.0

then I did this to get a long-lived access token but this expires in 2 months..

```
response = requests.get(url=f"https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{client_id}/accounts?access_token={long_lived_access_token}")
print(response.json())
```

so my question is essentially what is the best way to get a short lived user access token without having to go into the UI?

Comment: There is no way to get a user token, without user interaction. You can implement the login flow within your app, if you don’t want to do it via Graph API Explorer.

Comment: hi @CBroe Can you explain this part more 'you can implement the login flow within your app'? I'm using Python to try to extract data from all of our Pages using Facebook's GraphAPI module, is there a tutorial or example on how to implement the login flow?

Comment: Basically, this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web, or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow